# Difference between double brackets and the $ sign

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, plyr, mean

Since I have to use a function in a loop, I have to use `dplyr` `group_by_at()` and `summarise_at()` function. Unfortunately, I am not able to use the complete function from `plyr` to prevent empty groups to be removed by using an Index. Or is there another option to prevent dplyr from dropping empty groups?

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
df1 <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(gear) %>%
    summarise(Mittelwert = mean(mpg, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    complete(gear, fill = list(Gewicht = 1))
df1

df2 <- mtcars %>%
    group_by_at(10) %>%
    summarise_at(1, mean, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
    complete(gear, fill = list(Gewicht = 1))
```

Comment: How is the question title related to the question content?

Comment: The question is how to write use the complete function for df2 not with the variable gear, but with an indixed variable (eg. mtcars[[1]] )